# There is nothing when executing history command

Tags: bash

When I execute `history` command, there is nothing to output. But there are more than 20000 records in the bash history file. And the HISTFILE is the right location from where history would read.

Is there any tips to troubleshoot this problem? The bash version is 4.2.46

Comment: Do you have a `PROMPT_COMMAND` or something that does `history -c`?

Comment: Thanks. Now I have worked around the problem. The problem was that value of `HISTSIZE` variable was not correct. I wanted to set the history size to be unlimited. Before bash-4.3, it should be left to be empty for unlimited size.